# Linear interpolation by group in R

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

Suppose the following data:

```
     Date        V1              V2
1 1996-01-04 0.04383562 days 0.1203920
2 1996-01-04 0.12054795 days 0.1094760
..............
3 1996-02-01 0.04383562 days 0.1081815
4 1996-02-01 0.12054795 days 0.1092450
..............
5 1996-03-01 0.04109589 days 0.1553875
6 1996-03-01 0.13687215 days 0.1469690
```

For each of the group dates (which i distinguished them by dots for ease), i want to do a simple linear interpolation: for a `V1=0.08` what `V2` i will get.

**What I have tried**:
first the most logical approach to use `approx`:

```
IV<-data %>% group_by(Date) %>% approx(V1,V2,xout=0.08)
```

but instead i get this error:

```
Error in approx(., V1, V2, xout = 0.08) : 
  invalid interpolation method
In addition: Warning message:
In if (is.na(method)) stop("invalid interpolation method") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

then i tried:

```
Results<-unsplit(lapply(split(data,data$Date),function(x){m<-lm(V2~V1,x)
                                                       cbind(x,predict(m,0.08))}),data$Date)
```

with an error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x[, 3] ~ x[, 2], data = x, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'x[, 3]'
```

I also tried the `dplyr` package with no results:

```
IV<-data %>% group_by(Date) %>% predict(lm(V2~V1,data=data,0.08)
```

which gave the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('grouped_df', 'tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you were getting in `approx` is because you are passing the `data.frame` as the first argument when using `%>%`.  so your call is `approx(df, v1, v2, xout=0.08)`.

You could accomplish the `approx` call using `data.table` in a one liner:

```
library(data.table)
#created as df instead of dt for use in dplyr solution later
df <- data.frame(grp=sample(letters[1:2],10,T),
             v1=rnorm(10),
             v2=rnorm(10))

dt <- data.table(df)

dt[, approx(v1,v2,xout=.08), by=grp]

#output
   grp    x          y
1:   b 0.08 -0.5112237
2:   a 0.08 -1.4228923
```

On a first pass to stay in the `tidyverse` my solution isnt so tidy; there is likely a cleaner way to do this in a pipeline, but i think it'll be hard to beat the `data.table` solution.

Solution forced into `magrittr` pipeline:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    group_by(grp) %>% 
    summarise(out=list(approx(v1,v2,xout=.08))) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(x=purrr::map_dbl(out,'x'),
           y=purrr::map_dbl(out,'y')) %>% 
    select(-out)

#output
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     grp     x          y
  <fctr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1      a  0.08 -1.4228923
2      b  0.08 -0.5112237
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but approx doesn't work well (returns NA) when I extrapolate, is that correct? 
It works perfectly for the interpolation part.